# draw coordinate Two dimensions graph of (x-y) visual basic

Tags: vb.net

---

hey every one I want to make a program that able to draw coordinate graph of Two dimensions of (x-y).when I enter a value in (x) text box and (y) text box and hit draw button it well draw the graph in the blue picture box . I searched in web sit but I found only one method that draw using the mouse and this not what I want .This is the image of the program and and it supposed to draw in white line like this image
[image]

```
Private Sub PictureBox2_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox2.MouseMove
    Static last As Point
    If e.Button = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        PictureBox2.CreateGraphics.DrawLine(Pens.White, last.X, last.Y, e.X, e.Y)
    End If
    last = e.Location
End Sub
```

this is the code that I found that draw using the mouse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be good to have a bit more details of your code, especially how and in what class you store the X and Y coordinate.  By the way you draw a line between 2 points so you would need two sets of X and Y coordinate boxes on your form.
After that it is as easy as what you found on the internet using the DrawLine method (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.drawline(v=vs.110).aspx), you just needs to fire it from the Click event of your "draw" button.

Hi again Ahmed
Here is a simple sample of a form that would draw a line when button is clicked.  Of course it would need more bootstrapping to make sure user only enter integer value for the number of pixels and in its basic form, (0,0) is the top left of the panel but it can easily be converted for a bottom left approach...
[image]

and

```
Class Form1

   Private Sub cmdDraw_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cmdDraw.Click
      Dim x1 As Integer = Integer.Parse(txtX1.Text)
      Dim y1 As Integer = Integer.Parse(txtY1.Text)
      Dim x2 As Integer = Integer.Parse(txtX2.Text)
      Dim y2 As Integer = Integer.Parse(txtY2.Text)
      pnlMap.CreateGraphics.DrawLine(New Pen(Color.Black), x1, y1, x2, y2)
   End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: I store the number the Dictionary method . and the reason because I want to a program of c n c control and something like that

Comment: Calling `CreateGraphics` is a mistake.  Anything you draw in this way will disappear if another window passes in front or if you minimize and restore.  As theBugger pointed out in his/her answer above, all drawing should occur in the Paint event of the panel.  In your Click event, you should just call `pnlMap.Invalidate` or `pnlMap.Refresh` to cause it to repaint.  Also, you are not disposing of your Pen.  There's no need to create pens of the basic colors.  Just use `Pens.Black` instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`Graphic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f956fzw1(v=vs.110).aspx) class inside the panel's [`Paint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.paint(v=vs.110).aspx) event

```
Private Sub Panel1_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs)

    ' Create pen.
    Using blackPen As New Pen(Color.Black, 3)

        ' Create points that define line.
        Dim point1 As New Point(100, 100)
        Dim point2 As New Point(500, 100)

        ' Draw line to screen.
        e.Graphics.DrawLine(blackPen, point1, point2)

    End Using
End Sub
```

Then call `Panle1.Invalidate()` to fire the `Paint` event

Comment: You should be sure to dispose of your Pen.